# Filter lines of a text file that do not match with any of the elements in an array

Tags: ruby

I have a text file like the following,

```
Joe is in London,    
Sathish in Newyork,   
Pandu in Sydney
```

whose lines mostly match elements of an array:

```
Array = [London, Newyork]
```

Text file and array are dynamic both content- and size-wise.

How can I filter the lines that don't match with any of the elements in the given array? How can I filter the line `"Pandu in Sydney"` line from the text file?

Comment: Do you want to extract these lines to array, remove them from text file or something else?

Comment: Want to remove the matching lines or get the lines which don't match with any of the elements in the array either will do

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'set'
```

First let's create the file.

```
arr =<<_
Joe is in London, England,    
Sathish in Newyork,   
Pandu in Sydney
_

FName = 'test'
File.write(FName, arr)
  #=> 70
```

We are given `targets`:

```
targets = ["London", "Newyork"].to_set
  #=> #<Set: {"London", "Newyork"}>
```

We can now read the file line-by-line, selecting lines that contain at least one of the words in `targets`:

```
File.foreach(FName).select { |line|
  line.strip.tr(',', '').split.any? { |word| targets.include? word } }
  #=> ["Joe is in London, England,\n", "Sathish in Newyork,\n"]
```

I could have made `targets` an array rather than a set, but word lookups are much faster when using a set, especially if `targets` is large.

If it is known that the city is always the last word in each line we can simplify.

```
str =<<_
Joe is in London,
Sathish in Newyork,
Pandu in Sydney,
_

File.write(FName, str)

File.foreach(FName).select { |line|
  targets.include?(line.rstrip.tr(',', '')[/\b\p{L}+\z/]) }
  #=> ["Joe is in London,\n", "Sathish in Newyork,\n"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the array contains strings, would something like this do the work?

```
text.each_line.reject {|line| cities.any?{|city| line.match?(/\w+\s+in\s+#{city}/)}}
```

I don't know if you want to remove the lines directly from the text or in the program's logic. That would return you an array of "in unknown city" lines.